# How to safely reverse Intl.numberFormat back to the original number format

Tags: flutter, dart

I have strings in the format

```
20,000.00
200,000.00
20,230.00
16,230.05
```

This where formatted using dart intl NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "ko-KR").

How can one reverse them back to their original numbers?:

```
20000
200000
20230
16230.05
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parse` method of `NumberFormat`:

```dart
final format = NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "ko-KR");
final String str = format.format(20000);
print(str);
final num number = format.parse(string);
print(number);
```

```
I/flutter ( 5486): 20,000.00
I/flutter ( 5486): 20000.0
```